# Why not receving email address using Google_Oauth2Service in php?

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-signin

Does anyone know how I can get the user email address?

My code is below:

```
require_once("sm/google/Google_Client.php");
    require_once("sm/google/contrib/Google_PlusService.php");
    require_once("sm/google/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php");   
    include_once("ErrorReporting.php");   



    $objError = new ErrorReporting();   
    $client = new Google_Client();

    $client->setApplicationName("myproject");
    //$client->setHttpClient($httpClient);


    // Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus to generate your
    // client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
    $client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri($callbackurl);
    $client->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLE_API_KEY);
    $client->setAccessType("online");
    $client->setApprovalPrompt("auto");
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
    $oauth2Service  = new Google_Oauth2Service($client); 
    $plus = new Google_PlusService($client);



$userinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo;
print_r($userinfo->get());


    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {


        try {
            $client->authenticate();
        } catch(Exception $e) {  
            $objError->reportError("Error! while authenticate through google",$e ,'dev');
        }

        $token = $client->getAccessToken();

        try {
        $userProfile = $plus->people->get("me");
        print_r($userProfile);
            exit();
        }  catch(Exception $e) {  

            //echo $e;
            $objError->reportError("Error! while login through google",$e ,'dev');
        }

        $id = $userProfile['id'];

        return array(
                'user' => $id,
                'network' => 'google',
                'userprofile' => $userProfile,
                'token' => $token,
                'loginUrl' => null,
                'logoutUrl' => null
        );
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        return array(
                'user' => 0,
                'network' => 'google',
                'userprofile' => $userProfile,
                'token' => null,
                'loginUrl' => $authUrl,
                'logoutUrl' => null
        );
    }
}
```

So not sure how I can get the email address using google oauth2service. As I tried to access it but no error appearing on screen but also no email address is fatched. I looked at the contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php class file and don't find the get() method so not sure what I am missing here.

Following two line of code is not returning any email information:

```
$userinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo;
    print_r($userinfo->get());
```

My PHP version is 5.3

My Google_Oauth2Service.php file looks like below:

```
    <?php
/*
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */


  /**
   * The "userinfo" collection of methods.
   * Typical usage is:
   *  <code>
   *   $oauth2Service = new Google_Oauth2Service(...);
   *   $userinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo;
   *  </code>
   */
  class Google_UserinfoServiceResource extends Google_ServiceResource {

    /**
     * (userinfo.get)
     *
     * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
     * @return Google_Userinfo
     */
    public function get($optParams = array()) {
      $params = array();
      $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
      $data = $this->__call('get', array($params));
      if ($this->useObjects()) {
        return new Google_Userinfo($data);
      } else {
        return $data;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * The "v2" collection of methods.
   * Typical usage is:
   *  <code>
   *   $oauth2Service = new Google_Oauth2Service(...);
   *   $v2 = $oauth2Service->v2;
   *  </code>
   */
  class Google_UserinfoV2ServiceResource extends Google_ServiceResource {

  }

  /**
   * The "me" collection of methods.
   * Typical usage is:
   *  <code>
   *   $oauth2Service = new Google_Oauth2Service(...);
   *   $me = $oauth2Service->me;
   *  </code>
   */
  class Google_UserinfoV2MeServiceResource extends Google_ServiceResource {

    /**
     * (me.get)
     *
     * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
     * @return Google_Userinfo
     */
    public function get($optParams = array()) {
      $params = array();
      $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
      $data = $this->__call('get', array($params));
      if ($this->useObjects()) {
        return new Google_Userinfo($data);
      } else {
        return $data;
      }
    }
  }

/**
 * Service definition for Google_Oauth2 (v2).
 *
 * <p>
 * Lets you access OAuth2 protocol related APIs.
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>
 * For more information about this service, see the
 * <a href="https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2" target="_blank">API Documentation</a>
 * </p>
 *
 * @author Google, Inc.
 */
class Google_Oauth2Service extends Google_Service {
  public $userinfo;
  public $userinfo_v2_me;
  /**
   * Constructs the internal representation of the Oauth2 service.
   *
   * @param Google_Client $client
   */
  public function __construct(Google_Client $client) {
    $this->servicePath = '';
    $this->version = 'v2';
    $this->serviceName = 'oauth2';

    $client->addService($this->serviceName, $this->version);
    $this->userinfo = new Google_UserinfoServiceResource($this, 

    $this->serviceName, 'userinfo', json_decode('{"methods": {"get": {"id": "oauth2.userinfo.get", "path": "oauth2/v2/userinfo", "httpMethod": "GET", "response": {"$ref": "Userinfo"}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]}}}', true));
        $this->userinfo_v2_me = new Google_UserinfoV2MeServiceResource($this, $this->serviceName, 'me', json_decode('{"methods": {"get": {"id": "oauth2.userinfo.v2.me.get", "path": "userinfo/v2/me", "httpMethod": "GET", "response": {"$ref": "Userinfo"}, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]}}}', true));


  }
}



class Google_Tokeninfo extends Google_Model {
  public $access_type;
  public $audience;
  public $email;
  public $expires_in;
  public $issued_to;
  public $scope;
  public $user_id;
  public $verified_email;
  public function setAccess_type( $access_type) {
    $this->access_type = $access_type;
  }
  public function getAccess_type() {
    return $this->access_type;
  }
  public function setAudience( $audience) {
    $this->audience = $audience;
  }
  public function getAudience() {
    return $this->audience;
  }
  public function setEmail( $email) {
    $this->email = $email;
  }
  public function getEmail() {
    return $this->email;
  }
  public function setExpires_in( $expires_in) {
    $this->expires_in = $expires_in;
  }
  public function getExpires_in() {
    return $this->expires_in;
  }
  public function setIssued_to( $issued_to) {
    $this->issued_to = $issued_to;
  }
  public function getIssued_to() {
    return $this->issued_to;
  }
  public function setScope( $scope) {
    $this->scope = $scope;
  }
  public function getScope() {
    return $this->scope;
  }
  public function setUser_id( $user_id) {
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
  }
  public function getUser_id() {
    return $this->user_id;
  }
  public function setVerified_email( $verified_email) {
    $this->verified_email = $verified_email;
  }
  public function getVerified_email() {
    return $this->verified_email;
  }
}

class Google_Userinfo extends Google_Model {
  public $birthday;
  public $email;
  public $family_name;
  public $gender;
  public $given_name;
  public $hd;
  public $id;
  public $link;
  public $locale;
  public $name;
  public $picture;
  public $timezone;
  public $verified_email;
  public function setBirthday( $birthday) {
    $this->birthday = $birthday;
  }
  public function getBirthday() {
    return $this->birthday;
  }
  public function setEmail( $email) {
    $this->email = $email;
  }
  public function getEmail() {
    return $this->email;
  }
  public function setFamily_name( $family_name) {
    $this->family_name = $family_name;
  }
  public function getFamily_name() {
    return $this->family_name;
  }
  public function setGender( $gender) {
    $this->gender = $gender;
  }
  public function getGender() {
    return $this->gender;
  }
  public function setGiven_name( $given_name) {
    $this->given_name = $given_name;
  }
  public function getGiven_name() {
    return $this->given_name;
  }
  public function setHd( $hd) {
    $this->hd = $hd;
  }
  public function getHd() {
    return $this->hd;
  }
  public function setId( $id) {
    $this->id = $id;
  }
  public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }
  public function setLink( $link) {
    $this->link = $link;
  }
  public function getLink() {
    return $this->link;
  }
  public function setLocale( $locale) {
    $this->locale = $locale;
  }
  public function getLocale() {
    return $this->locale;
  }
  public function setName( $name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }
  public function setPicture( $picture) {
    $this->picture = $picture;
  }
  public function getPicture() {
    return $this->picture;
  }
  public function setTimezone( $timezone) {
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
  }

 public function getTimezone() {
    return $this->timezone;
  }
  public function setVerified_email( $verified_email) {
    $this->verified_email = $verified_email;
  }
  public function getVerified_email() {
    return $this->verified_email;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you insist of using a PHP version that is horribly outdated? It has received its last updates more than five years ago, and you cannot expect that current SDKs still provide support for that

Comment: I stopped reading at PHP 5.3 :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're using this but I've tried with `v1-master` branch of google `apiclient` and I'm able to fetch user's email address

```php
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName('Login to Test Project');
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL);
$client->addScope(['email', 'profile']);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    try {
        $token = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $Oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
        $info = $Oauth->userinfo->get();
        print_r($info);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        print_r($exception->getMessage());
    }    
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: '.$authUrl);
}
```

Please share your composer.json file, so that I can try with your configurations to provide a better solution.

Comment: Just a guess but his problem could have been the usage of older API, in your example its Google_Service_Oauth2 in his it's Google_Oauth2Service which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a couple things on your end that could be causing you some grief. Your order of operations seems to be reversed. You shouldn't be calling this:

```
$userinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo;
print_r($userinfo->get());
```

before this:

```
$client->authenticate();
```

Also, you should be sending the code along with the client.

So, something like this should get you some proper output:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

$code = $_GET['code'];
    try {
        $client->authenticate($code);
    } catch(Exception $e) {  
        $objError->reportError("Error! while authenticate through google",$e ,'dev');
    }
$userinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo;
print_r($userinfo->get());
}
```

Give that a try, and then let us know if you're on the right track. Also, Google Plus has been deprecated, so I would recommend you don't use those libraries any longer.

Comment: Hi I did that and my code is not executing further as get() method breaks the code because thr is no get() method found. So if you can have a look at my google_Oauth2Service.php file then maybe you catch something which I am missing

Comment: Hi @Nixopax did you find anything yet? like if I use any other method from google_Oauth2Service.php file to extract email details?

Comment: Hi @Jimil you're right there is no get() method in the class, because it's an action that is called on the userinfo itself. I'm looking at my code and the difference I've seen with mine is this.

`$userinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo->get();`

That way, it's called all at once. Then, it's just `print_r($userinfo);`

Comment: Hi @Nixopax, you are right and that's I have also found with 5.4 google Oauth PHP client version. However, the reason I mentioned my issue here and also place the bounty is that if someone knows how to fix this in 5.3 version as mentioned in my question. Otherwise I know that using get() method I can access this information in version 5.4 or higher but in my case I don't have that version.

Comment: so if you can fix in version 5.3 or anyone else can find the fix on this would be great. As I am sure thr must be some fix.

Comment: @Jimil can you please share your composer.json file